# Codeigniter categories and sub categories function and pass to smarty variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

This is my codeigniter code for categories and sub categories when i echo the results outside the first foreach or pass results to smarty it only outputs last rows with last main id.
But echo within the first foreach before closing } returns all results.

```
function getAllCats(){
    $this->load->model('mHtml', 'mnMod');
    $main_cat = $this->mnMod->getncats();
    $all_cat = '';
    foreach($main_cat as $mcat){
        $all_cat = '<li><h3><a href="{base_url()}'.$mcat->cname.'">'.$mcat->cname.'</a></h3>';
        $sub_cat = $this->mnMod->getscats($mcat->categoryid);
            foreach($sub_cat as $scat){
                $all_cat .= '<a href="{base_url()}'.$scat->cname.'">'.$scat->cname.'</a><br />';
                }
        $all_cat .= '</li>';
    }
  //  echo $all_cat; die;
    $this->smarty->assign("nav", $all_cat);
}
```

Results returned with mymethod.

**Power Inverters**

Off Grid Pure Sine Wave

Grid Tie String

Micro Grid Tie

**Results i want to achieve and pass to smarty variable**

**Solar Panels**

Monocrystalline

Polycrystalline

Flexible Solar

**Charge Controllers**

PWM

MPPT Technology

**Power Inverters**

Off Grid Pure Sine Wave

Grid Tie String

Micro Grid Tie

Comment: You should be keeping all your markup in your view, especially if you are using Smarty.

Comment: what when i have to retrieve all sub categories through main cat ids  i have to call model again for sub categories i cannot call model from smarty

Comment: ALL the logic can be achieved in the controller. You know you can perform a foreach in Smarty, right?

Comment: Can you help me with written code.

Comment: I can run foreach in smarty  but i have to call model again which  i cant call from smarty view.

Comment: Bare with me, I will show you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue what i did i get all parent categories by one mysql query and in another i select all categories, simply i assign variables to smarty and foreach those results against each parent category.

```
$main_Categories = $this->model->all_categories();

$this->smarty->assign("main_Categories ", $main_Categories );
```

//On Smarty page

```
    {foreach $main_Categories  $cat}
     {if $cat->parentid = 'your parent id'} // parent id will be same for all main ids.
       {$cat->category_name}<br />
    {assign 'cat_id'  $cat->cat_id}
    {foreach $main_Categories  as $sub}
      {if $cat_id eq $sub->parent_id}
        {$sub->category_name}<br />
           {/if}
         {/foreach}
         {/if}
         {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your $main_cats and assign sub_categories for each one. Good practice is to ensure $main_cats is an array before doing this.

Controller:

```
function getAllCats() {
    $this->load->model('mHtml', 'mnMod');
    $main_cats = $this->mnMod->getncats();
    if(is_array($main_cats))
    foreach($main_cats as &$mcat) {
        $mcat['subcat'] = $this->mnMod->getscats($mcat->categoryid);
    }

    $this->smarty->assign("cats", $main_cats);
}
```

View:

```
{if $cats}
     {foreach from=$cats item=cat}
        <li><h3><a href="{$cat.cname|base_url}">{$cat.cname}</a></h3>
        {foreach from=$cat item=sub_cat}
            <a href="{$sub_cat.cname|base_url}">{$sub_cat.cname}</a><br />
        {/foreach}
        </li>
     {/foreach}
{else}
    <p>No cats found</p>
{/if}
```